# Scenario based Use case point estimation counting

Tags: estimation

I am new to use case base estimation technique. I have the following scenario and facing little difficult to conclude my use case point count. Suppose I need to execute 3 steps one after another. Each of these steps, by themselves does not leave the system in a consistent state. So from use case point counting should I consider 1 use case having 3 transactions? Is my understanding correct?

Also for use case estimation along with functional document, I must require design document right? Without design document, I can still estimate with functional document but it will not be accurate right?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm a practicing agile coach and I'm not exactly sure what you are talking about. Could you provide more context or possibly point to some online documentation on "Ues Case Base Estimation"?

Comment: Online document for use case estimation is [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/estimation_techniques/estimation_techniques_use_case_points.htm)

Answer (score 0):

All right, looks like this is for school, right?

It will be hard for us to answer as the answer is the book answer, not the practical answer.

Practically speaking, trying to estimate by Use Cases is something not used in any modern agile approaches. `[Use Cases are not User Stories][1]`Any estimates you get are going to be flawed based on trying to estimate something bigger than can be reasonably estimated.

Sorry, based on what you are showing us, I can't help you directly. It's not something I would ever use in day to day business and if I had a client using this I would work to coach them away from it. The only real advice I can offer you is if this is in your curriculum you may want to ask if this is teaching you practical job skills instead of what the school thinks is relevant. There are a lot of education "bodies" out there right now that are teaching "agile" in such a way that it will be useless to you in an actual job.

Best of luck.